# Does reverse actually reverse a Python iterator?

Tags: python, python-2.7, iterator, reverse

So I can create a reverse iterator on a list:

```
list(reversed([0,1,2,3]))

[3, 2, 1, 0]
```

I assume this simply calls `getitem` from index `len(...)-1` to `0`. But then I cannot also do this:

```
list(reversed(xrange(4)))

[3, 2, 1, 0]
```

Now I am a bit confused. Does this create the list from `xrange(4)` and then reverse it? If not, how does it know what the last element is and how to go backwards? I read the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reversed) but it didn't help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`reversed()` looks for a [`__reversed__` special method](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__reversed__) on the object. List objects provide this, and so does `xrange()`:

```
>>> xrange(4).__reversed__()
<rangeiterator object at 0x106e2fa50>
```

The iterator object simply produces the values in reverse, no list object is produced.

For objects that do *not* implement `__reversed__`, the `reversed()` function uses the length and the `__getitem__` method; e.g. `reversed()` is essentially equivalent to:

```
def reversed(seq):
    try:
        return seq.__reversed__()
    except AttributeError:
        return (seq[i] for i in xrange(len(seq) - 1, -1 , -1))
```

where the second part is a generator expression, evaluating lazily. The generator then accesses each item in turn starting at index (length - 1) all the way down to index 0.

Answer (score 4):

`reversed()` can only take a sequence -- if it took generic iterators, it couldn't know what the final value was without exhausting the iterator and storing all the values.

Luckily, `xrange` returns an xrange object that works as a sequence:

```
>>> x = xrange(10)
>>> len(x)
10
>>> x[9]
9
```

It also happens to have an actual `__reversed__` method, but that's a special case of having all the sequence methods.

Answer (score 1):

Just compare the two:

```
In [2]: reversed(xrange(4))
Out[2]: <rangeiterator at 0x7fa83291bde0>

In [3]: list(reversed(xrange(4)))
Out[3]: [3, 2, 1, 0]

In [4]: reversed([0,1,2,3])
Out[4]: <listreverseiterator at 0x7fa8328be2d0>

In [5]: list(reversed([0,1,2,3]))
Out[5]: [3, 2, 1, 0]
```